# How can I get my test project (XUnit) to load references from a specific folder when testing my C# project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a C# Project A (.NET Framework 4.8) that I want to test with XUnit and Visual Studio 2022.
Project A has many references to various dlls and contains about 20 WPF dialogs, each written in MVVM. The references are all placed in a certain folder C:\runtime\ and added via hintpath.

1. I added the project that I want to test as project reference. Copy local is set to true.
2. First I created a subfolder for the first dialog I want to test.
3. Created a file Dialog1ViewModelTests.cs
4. Created a constructor which has to be called before every test:

```
public class Dialog1ViewModelTest
{
    public Dialog1ViewModelTest()
    {
        Dialog1ViewModel _viewModel = new Dialog1ViewModel ();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }
}
```

Running the test shows me the following message:

- System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'X.Y.Z.Forms.Wpf, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3f16fc4c439f528a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

This is one of the assemblys which are referenced by Project A. In project A these assemblies are
added as followed:

```
<Reference Include="X.Y.Z.Forms.Wpf">
  <HintPath>C:\runtime\X.Y.Z.Forms.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

So I added the reference the same way in the testproject (Copy Local = false). But still the same error:

- System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'X.Y.Z.Forms.Wpf, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3f16fc4c439f528a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

If I set "copy local" to true, then the DLLs are also found. But this is not an option, because these are tons of DLLs. Why can't the test project just load them from the path C:\runtime\ like the normal project does?

How can I get this to work?

Edit:

I got this working with MSTest:
Inside the .runsettings file I specified

```
    <AssemblyResolution>
      <Directory path="C:\runtime\" includeSubDirectories="true"/>
    </AssemblyResolution>
```

Now the dependencies are found.

Comment: Are you sure your test framework and wpf framework same frameworks. Or are you running your tests as administrator

Comment: Yes. They are both based on .NET Framework 4.8. But I switched from XUnit to MSTest. Now I can specify my dependencies in the .runsettings file <AssemblyResolution>
      <Directory path="C:\runtime\" includeSubDirectories="true"/>
    </AssemblyResolution>